# How to use summarise() on a long data in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have a long data, where the SBP/DBP span the rows of the data.

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
ID ITEM_NAME ITEM_VALUE DATE
1  SBP       154        20210102
1  DBP       66         20210111
2  SBP       115        20210513
2  SBP       113        20210513
2  DBP       62         20210413", header = TRUE)
```

I would like to transform it to a wide form, using summary functions with the `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::summarise` functions and the stats are:

- No. of measurements for DBP and SBP
- Indicator if the no. of measurements of DBP and SBP are at least 2
- Mean values of DBP and SBP
- Latest values of DBP and SBP

**Desired data**

```
df_new <- read.table(text = "
ID    DBP_no DBP_no_atleast2 DBP_mean DBP_latest SBP_no SBP_no_atleast2 SBP_mean SBP_latest
1     1      0               66       66         1      0               154      154       
2     1      0               62       62         2      1               114      113", header = TRUE)
```

**Method**

I attempted the following code, which gave me the aggregated data with each row being a unique combination of `ID` and `ITEM_NAME`.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID, ITEM_NAME) %>% 
  summarise(meas_no = n(),
            meas_no_atleast2 = +(meas_no >= 2),
            meas_mean = mean(ITEM_VALUE),
            meas_latest = dplyr::last(ITEM_VALUE, DATE)) %>% 
  ungroup()
# ID ITEM_NAME meas_no meas_no_atleast2 meas_mean meas_latest
# <int> <chr>       <int>            <int>     <dbl>       <int>
#     1 DBP             1                0        66          66
#     1 SBP             1                0       154         154
#     2 DBP             1                0        62          62
#     2 SBP             2                1       114         113
```

So, I had to tidy it further using tidyr::pivot_longer and tidyr::pivot_wider, to get the desired results.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID, ITEM_NAME) %>% 
  summarise(meas_no = n(),
            meas_no_atleast2 = +(meas_no >= 2),
            meas_mean = mean(ITEM_VALUE),
            meas_latest = dplyr::last(ITEM_VALUE, DATE)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(ID, ITEM_NAME)) %>% 
  mutate(name = str_remove(name, "meas_")) %>% 
  unite(ITEM_NAME, c(ITEM_NAME, name)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = ITEM_NAME, values_from = value)
# ID    DBP_no DBP_no_atleast2 DBP_mean DBP_latest SBP_no SBP_no_atleast2 SBP_mean SBP_latest
# <chr> <chr>  <chr>           <chr>    <chr>      <chr>  <chr>           <chr>    <chr>     
# 1     1      0               66       66         1      0               154      154       
# 2     1      0               62       62         2      1               114      113
```

It meets the objective, but it is so long. I am just wondering if there's a shortcut to this, so it is readable to other R users if I would like to share.

**Alternative method (does not work)**

I attempted the following code, but it's not giving what I want either:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(DBP_no = n()[ITEM_NAME == "DBP"],
            DBP_no_atleast2 = +(DBP_no >= 2),
            DBP_mean = mean(ITEM_VALUE[ITEM_NAME == "DBP"]),
            DBP_latest = dplyr::last(ITEM_VALUE[ITEM_NAME == "DBP"], DATE[ITEM_NAME == "DBP"]),
            SBP_no = n()[ITEM_NAME == "SBP"],
            SBP_no_atleast2 = +(SBP_no >= 2),
            SBP_mean = mean(ITEM_VALUE[ITEM_NAME == "SBP"]),
            SBP_latest = dplyr::last(ITEM_VALUE[ITEM_NAME == "SBP"], DATE[ITEM_NAME == "SBP"])) %>% 
  ungroup()
# ID DBP_no DBP_no_atleast2 DBP_mean DBP_latest SBP_no SBP_no_atleast2 SBP_mean SBP_latest
# <int>  <int>           <int>    <dbl>      <int>  <int>           <int>    <dbl>      <int>
#     1     NA              NA       66         66      2               1      154        154
#     2     NA              NA       62         62      3               1      114        113
#     2     NA              NA       62         62     NA              NA      114        113
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `summarise` you can directly do the `pivot_wider` step -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID, ITEM_NAME) %>% 
  summarise(meas_no = n(),
            meas_no_atleast2 = +(meas_no >= 2),
            meas_mean = mean(ITEM_VALUE),
            meas_latest = dplyr::last(ITEM_VALUE, DATE)) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = ITEM_NAME, values_from = meas_no:meas_latest)
```